# Alternatives to pass-by-reference updates on list in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class that has one or more input list and it needs to process and update other lists which are scoped outside of the class. What can be a good pattern to use here?
I've tried the following two patterns here:

1. Update directly by using pass-by-reference
2. Using callbacks to let the caller handle how they want to deal with the update

**Examples**

1. Using direct update

```java
public class SomeClass {
  public void process(List<String> inputList, List<StringContainer> errorContainerList, List<String> validList) {
    for (String str : inputList) {
      if (someCondition) {
        validList.add(str);
      } else {
        errorContainerList.add(new StringContainer(str, new SomeError()));
      }
    }
  }
}

void someCaller(List<String> inputList) {
    List<String> validList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<StringContainer> errorContainerList = new ArrayList<>();

    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
    obj.process(inputList, errorContainerList, validList);

    // Similarly,
    validList.remove(...);
    errorContainerList.add(...);
}
```

2. Using callbacks

```java
public interface StringErrorHandler {
    void handle(String str, SomeError error);
}

public interface ValidInputHandler {
    void handle(String str);
}

public class SomeClass {
  public void process(List<String> inputList, StringErrorHandler errorHandler, ValidInputHandler validInputHandler) {
    for (String str : inputList) {
      if (someCondition) {
        validInputHandler.handle(str);
      } else {
        errorHandler.handle(str, new SomeError());
      }
    }
  }
}

void someCaller(List<String> inputList) {
    List<String> validList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<StringContainer> errorContainerList = new ArrayList<>();

    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
    obj.process(inputList, new StringErrorHandler() {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(String str, SomeError error) {
            errorContainerList.add(new StringContainer(str, error));
        }
    }, new ValidInputHandler() {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(String str) {
            validList.add(str);
        }
    });

    // Similarly,
    validList.remove(...);
    errorContainerList.add(...);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "good" pattern? What makes a pattern "good"?

Comment: What is the problem with doing it either of your ways? Is there an exception?

Comment: @Sweeper Since similar case is very frequently occurring, I'm wondering if there are any preexisting patterns that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @NomadMaker Here the problem with the 1st approach is that if the number of input and number of output increase, then the number of parameters for the method increase which can make refactoring the code harder. For 2nd approach, I'm wondering if it will make the debugging confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use neither of them. They are both unnescessarily complicated. Let's think what is your actual problem here? If you didn't care for error handling, you'd probably write something like this:

```
    public List<String> process(List<String> inputList) {
    List<String> validList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : inputList) {
        if (someCondition) {
            validList.add(str);
        }
    }
    return validList;
}
```

So the problem is that you can't return two values from a method in java. But to handle that you can add a simple nested class having these 2 values and the client then can easily extract them:

```
public ProcessResult process(List<String> inputList) {
    List<StringContainer> errorContainerList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> validList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : inputList) {
        if (someCondition) {
            validList.add(str);
        } else {
            errorContainerList.add(new StringContainer(str, new SomeError()));
        }
    }
    return new ProcessResult(validList, errorContainerList)
}

public static class ProcessResult{
    public final List<String> validList;
    public final List<StringContainer> errorContainerList;

    public ProcessResult(List<String> validList, List<StringContainer> errorContainerList) {
        this.validList = validList;
        this.errorContainerList = errorContainerList;
    }
}
   void someCaller(List<String> inputList) {
    List<String> validList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<StringContainer> errorContainerList = new ArrayList<>();

    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
    ProcessResult pr=obj.process(inputList);
    validList.addAll(pr.validList);
    errorContainerList.addAll(pr.errorContainerList);
    

}
```

This is better for few reasons, but most important are, that there are no side effects to your method and that the result of the method is explicitly returned, which is what we're supposed to do in java

Comment: In case of frequent calls, this solution will create a lot of temporary variable (ProcesResult). Do you think this will cause any issues on the GC?

Comment: Java is really good at dealing with redundant objects. 99.999% of time you don't have to think about that until you have actual problems with performance (check premature optimization).